# How to generate lines with specific direction from points

Tags: python-3.x, line, point

I have a list of points, spaced roughly 2.5 meters apart. Some points are closer or farther from each other than this distance. I want to create lines in a northwest-southeast direction (as picture), with each line spaced 3.5 meters apart (the orange colour lines on the picture). Only points approximately 2.5 meters apart will be used to generate these lines; others much larger or smaller this 2.5 meters will be ignored (points with blue colour on the picture). How can I achieve this using Python?

Below are my points coordinates in NZTM ((New Zealand Transverse Mercator) coordinate system):

```
[(1894419.1676073996, 5763028.664140096), (1894422.2213155003, 5763024.046833784), (1894420.0587863764, 5763025.115224303), (1894423.6198921362, 5763026.953786211), (1894428.6673662942, 5763025.44441213), (1894433.6791538028, 5763023.84005034), (1894431.2709350334, 5763024.518364979), (1894424.4628495527, 5763019.741958309), (1894418.552026459, 5763020.977293945), (1894426.1201751372, 5763020.541515332), (1894425.098325993, 5763023.161571276), (1894421.4757215753, 5763020.084169364), (1894429.1731958333, 5763018.196336435), (1894431.0624828963, 5763021.150793614), (1894427.030502974, 5763018.575131353), (1894431.358736312, 5763017.042347838), (1894434.2830495937, 5763020.360075035), (1894427.63269562, 5763021.993720094), (1894434.4315248383, 5763016.4181067785), (1894429.3290980253, 5763022.375569618), (1894436.5130415447, 5763018.797155001), (1894430.2919487664, 5763020.59701773), (1894442.349830174, 5763020.382214543), (1894444.613833068, 5763019.55167036), (1894439.5182284731, 5763018.015789331), (1894443.119595849, 5763016.3434212115), (1894439.221634359, 5763021.666818723), (1894438.1652611047, 5763015.311326039), (1894437.2836783128, 5763019.3934357185), (1894439.1741247233, 5763023.30417553), (1894436.7832011608, 5763015.215020707), (1894447.550798541, 5763018.68991359), (1894449.8506622687, 5763014.1431029895), (1894453.0226453207, 5763017.377600503), (1894449.69216738, 5763017.904890895), (1894446.8563310057, 5763015.145445534), (1894450.3979221154, 5763018.293394697), (1894455.816006057, 5763016.24536609), (1894458.0750947343, 5763015.325456924), (1894461.1790076736, 5763014.36164566), (1894442.2540249284, 5763012.611625285), (1894445.3683168935, 5763011.326336556), (1894445.1707855416, 5763010.111739053), (1894438.5502295122, 5763014.022023426), (1894447.4462702433, 5763010.54086871), (1894452.8437993815, 5763009.307925301), (1894450.4492029678, 5763009.814127336), (1894452.8499273518, 5763012.848422013), (1894464.789408084, 5763005.320750063), (1894459.8805866744, 5763007.160673708), (1894458.4096890287, 5763011.538647735), (1894462.6474522278, 5763006.100286745), (1894464.0276780194, 5763013.434098876), (1894461.3182516545, 5763010.504632506), (1894458.1730329096, 5763007.341462506), (1894464.1083376976, 5763009.950540608), (1894455.8643732145, 5763012.339883302), (1894461.1549719162, 5763006.205525867), (1894410.2756318608, 5763034.764022888), (1894415.1489418708, 5763030.3554201), (1894414.8469242072, 5763027.367206241), (1894411.2591219312, 5763029.693712353), (1894409.2758570546, 5763031.6195787955), (1894417.044738615, 5763025.852944607), (1894412.7090903986, 5763032.185084512), (1894413.1687709, 5763028.492344245), (1894413.3173584584, 5763022.003086638), (1894416.135296831, 5763021.759962137), (1894455.752431132, 5763008.228598645), (1894467.4588890132, 5763008.448857379), (1894467.8260459353, 5763012.015524623), (1894469.2422226348, 5763006.665523757), (1894470.6583993346, 5763003.570915414), (1894470.5534973568, 5763009.865034079), (1894472.6515369117, 5763006.770425735), (1894467.563790991, 5763002.679248603)]
```

[image]

Comment: How would you do it without Python?

Comment: By "create lines" do you mean you simply want to superimpose some manually-determined lines in a graph? Or do you want to perform some kind of linear regression to automatically determine which points belong to which lines?

Comment: @ Gaberocksall: I would like to perfom some of linear regression to automatically determine which points belong to which lines

Comment: @ mkrieger1: The line on the pictures is the one i manually draw. i would like to this automatically using python

Comment: How does the Python code know which input points are the blue ones?

Comment: And earlier I meant: what process did you use to determine where to draw the lines manually?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Good question. I think the process may define how many lines need to be generated and the distance criteria between points and generated lines.